# Cordova File api : getFile issue in android

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3.5

environment : Android

within the app im creating a file at the location `"/data/data/com.my.app/changes/123456789/123456789.json"`
and i have cross checked that the file exists using custom cordova android plugin.

When trying to access this file using cordova File api as shown below. the api simply fails giving 1000 code.

```
var path = "/changes/123456789/123456789.json"
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, 
                    function(fileSystem){
                        console.log('in got FS');
                        fileSystem.root.getFile(path,{create:true, exclusive: false},
                                function(fileEntry){
                                    console.log('gotFileEntry');
                                },
                                function(err){
                                    console.log('gotFileEntry fail');
                                    console.log('err.code');
                                    console.log(err.code);

                                    }
                                );

                    }, 
                    function(){
                        console.log('fail');
                        }
                    );
```

Im getting an error code as "1000" which i believe is "file not found".

As per the new Plugin docs the path to the file should be relative to filesystem root.
I think the issue is with the way im passing the file path.

the same is working when tested on iOS device, the issue is only with ANDROID.

Please let me know where exactly im going wrong. As im totally stuck.
Any help is highly appreciated.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Error 1000 is actually an unknown error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi after a lot of digging [Cordova file api](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/blob/master/doc/index.md) and with the help from the [post](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2014/11/5/Cordova-Example-Writing-to-a-file) , was able to access the files in ANDROID.

used

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.dataDirectory, function(dir) {
    console.log("got main dir",dir);
    dir.getFile("log.txt", {create:true}, function(file) {
        console.log("got the file", file);

    });
});
```

to get the file entry in Android. this works fine for iOS also.